# Execution detail function on Logistic Regression

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to see the details when I run this code:

1. [model.fit(x_train,y_train)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UdIM.png)
2. [model.fit(x_train,y_train) >> Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNKMP.png)

Comment: Try: ```display(model)```, maybe it will work

Comment: Hi @PatricioLoncomilla it still doesn't work with the code